# Error in fread - file does not exist or is non-readable

Tags: r, csv, fread

I am trying to use `fread()` to load a `.csv` file into R. It worked fine about a month ago.

I get the following error message (The Drive: is a much longer file name and I have anonymised some other bits)

> Error in fread("//Drive:/folders/my_file.csv") :    File
> 'C:\Users\Pendragon\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeo6xNb\file24a836c41a8a'
> does not exist or is non-readable.
> getwd()=='C:/Users/Pendragon/OneDrive - DragonsRUs/A Folder' In
> addition: Warning message: In (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system
> else shell)(paste0("(",  :   '(//Drive:/folders/my_file.csv) >
> C:\Users\Pendragon\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeo6xNb\file24a836c41a8a'
> execution failed with error code 1

The code is stored in another folder, and neither file is anywhere near my OneDrive, although that has been opened as I have a markdown file stored there to write about the results of this bit of code.

How can I get this to work again? I get the same error both on my computer and using a server based version of R.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you, as we don't have your file or your box. That said, I suggest you check if your instance of R has access to said file or its containing folder (by trying from the console).